# locate mysql function doesnt play nice with unicodes?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have the following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `keywords` 
WHERE name LIKE  '%ba%'
ORDER BY LOCATE(  'ba', name ) , name
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

this query should sort result by the appreance of 'ba' in side keywords.name. but, I'm getting some weird behavior on some special chars:if - for example - i have the word Ghurabā the query 
like %ba% will find it. but, it seems that locate(Ghurabā,ba) will return 0 - meaning as pattern was not found in string

**any idea how to overcome this issue?**

`p.s` -some useful data:

the result of the query above :

> Ghurabā'
>
> Khuṭabā'
>
> qabā\
>
> Ribāṭ
>
> ba'urchi (cook)
>
> Baghdad
>   ...

note that it does work for "regular english characters" but there is a mismatch between the like and the locate function

Using Collcation: utf8_general_ci (got the same result with utf_unicode_ci)
mysql:effected version mysql 5.5/5.6 ( and probably lower)

**EDIT:**

expected result of the query above should be something like 
'

> Baghdad
>
> ba'urchi (cook)
>
> qabā\
>
> Ribāṭ
>
> Ghurabā'
>
> Khuṭabā'

note : order by the distance of `ab` from the beginning of the word and then order by name

...

Comment: Do you want the query to find strings like "Ghurabā'?

Comment: i want the query order the result: first all the result starting with my query key. then all other result. and yes `ā` should be treated as `a` this actully works with `like` but doesnt work(for some reason) with `locate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use BINARY operator to compare strings. Check these query -

```
SELECT
  name,
  name LIKE BINARY '%ba%',
  name LIKE '%ba%',
  LOCATE('ba', name)
FROM
  `keywords`;
```

From the documentation:

- [LOCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)- this function is multi-byte safe
- [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html) - performs matching on a per-character basis

Comment: `like` works for me with out the binary. `locate` however does not work. in your example you use locate with out binary, is it typo? moreover binary makes the query `case sensitive`..

Comment: seems like `locate` doesn't like `unicode` and  i should look for other solution than using `locate`, isn't?

Comment: Not that LOCATE doesn't like unicode. Just LOCATE use per-byte comparison.